# Displaying related data in Web API 2 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, rest

Im having some issues with the Web API part of my asp.net MVC-application. The application works fine when using MVC-controllers and views, but when trying to return a Order and its OrderItem's through my web api 2-controller I get this error message:

The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

I gather there is something wrong with the serialization of the MenuItems. I have tried removing the Virtual-keyword from the classes and using Include to manually include the MenuItems but still get the same error.

Do I need to make a ViewModel for this just to return the data? I have also tried JSON.NET and get the same errors.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual MenueItem MenueItem { get; set; }
}

public class MenueItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller method:

```
    // GET: api/Orders
    public IQueryable<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        var orders = db.Orders.Include(c => c.OrderItems);
        return orders;
    }
```

Comment: There's a circular reference `MenueItem` - `OrderItems` even when lazy loading doesn't occur. You can tell the serializer to ignore reference loops.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im testing AutoMapper now and might go that route, but how would you ignore reference loops?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the converter to ignore the loop reference like:

```
var orders = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.GetOrders(), new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```